# Error: Cannot find module '@adminjs/design-system'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, adminjs

I installed AdminJS and was trying to run my application but I am coming across this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eL31.png)

It says:
Error: Cannot find module '@adminjs/design-system'

Even though design-system exists and I even added it as a require statement

const AdminJSDesignSystem = require("./@adminjs/design-system");

I also tried installing it again but it gave a huge error
[Right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yChcd.png)

Please help me fix this. I have got here after being through so many errors and fixing them and even now these errors won't stop popping up.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are importing it using a relative path.

You should change that to just the package name

e.g. `const AdminJSDesignSystem = require("@adminjs/design-system");`

Comment: Tried doing this but kept getting the error :/

Comment: At this point, it's probably worth doing a fresh install of Node and NPM - making sure you are on the latest version

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
const AdminJSDesignSystem = require("@adminjs/design-system");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed the official guide of [AdminJS](https://docs.adminjs.co/tutorial-installation-instructions.html) and [adminjs/design-system](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/adminjs-design-system#readme) that:

1. You have the admin user right to install things on your machine.
2. You have installed one of `Express`, `Hapi` and `Koajs`. If not,

   ```js
   npm install express express-formidable
   ```
3. You have installed AdminJS. If not,

   ```js
   npm install adminjs @adminjs/express
   ```
4. Finally, install according to the official doc:

   ```js
   npm install styled-components @adminjs/design-system
   ```

Comment: Installed everything again. Getting a new error now.                                               
    C:\Program Files\airline\adminjs\lib\backend\utils\resources-factory\resources-factory.js:95
      const resourceObject = rawResource.resource || rawResource;
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resource')

Comment: This is because your rawResource object does not contain the property 'resource'. From now on this is not the problem on installation but how you input necessary data correctly.